# Convergence Of Variance of a sequence of truncated functions

Tags: probability

Assume that we have a real valued function $f$ defined on the set of non-negative integers and we truncate in the sense that
$$
f_k(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    k       & f\geq k\\
    f(x)  & \text{else}\\
    -k  & f \leq -k
  \end{cases}$$

Also let $X$ be a poisson random variable of mean $\mu$. Does it hold that $\operatorname{Var}[f_k(X)]$ converge to $Var[f(X)]$ as $k$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: Have you written the question correctly? A probability distribution can't be negative.

Comment: @RowanS : I don't see anything in the question about a "probability distribution" being negative. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Do you have any additional conditions on what $X$ is? See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200573/variance-of-truncated-normal-distribution) question, for example.

Comment: Yes sorry i fixed it.

Comment: @SpawnKilleR See *Modeling Poisson variables with positive spatial dependence* by Kaiser and Cressie (1996) for some results on the winsorized Poisson distribution. I finally came up with a proof that the variance converges, but I'm exhausted so I will have to type it up later.